# Why can't I call the child process when I put it C:/Windows/System32/?

Tags: process, operating-system

I wrote a Project.exe that shows Hello World. Write a main process to create a child process of Project.exe. However, when I put Projetc.exe on C:/Windows/System32/, I can't create the child process of Project.exe correctly, but it can be created normally when I put it in other directories.

The main program is as follows：

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    wchar_t *p = (wchar_t*)TEXT("C:/Windows/System32/Project1.exe");
    CreateProcess(p, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);

    DWORD CurId = GetCurrentProcessId();    //Get the ID of the current process
    DWORD Pid = pi.dwProcessId;             //ID of the created process
    DWORD Tid = pi.dwThreadId;              //The main thread ID of the created child process
    printf("the ID of the current process:  %d\nID of the created process:  %d\nThe main thread ID of the created child process  %d\n", CurId, Pid, Tid);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, -1);
}
```

The result of the operation is：

[image]

If I put Project.exe under E:/, the result is

[image]

What is the reason for this, how do I need to change it to run successfully under /System32/?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is, if you want to know why a call isn't doing what you expect, you should first look at the return status to find out whether the call worked.

The documentation for `CreateProcess` tells you it returns non-zero for success, zero for failure.  You are not looking at the return value, so your code has no knowledge of success or failure.

Furthermore, on failure, GetLastError() will return a reason for failure. That might tell you what's going on.

In short, you need "if return value is zero, print value of GetLastError() and exit".